# How to modify maximum session duration of a role using python boto3 library

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

We are using Python boto3 library and are assuming a role through a profile. The reason for assuming role is S3 bucket we want to access is accessible only through that role. Now I see aws profile's AccessToken doesn't expire but the role we are assuming using this profile does expire in 1 hour. This results in following error:

```
An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The provided token has expired
```

I have found in AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-managingrole-editing-api.html) that there is option to do this but it's not clear. I tried getting `DurationSeconds` parameter from session object or client object but couldn't find it.

I tried

```py
boto_client.get_object_attributes(Bucket='bucket_name', Key='secret_access_key', ObjectAttributes=['LastModified'])`
```

but get error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the GetObjectAttributes operation: Invalid attribute name specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the session duration when you assume the role with `DurationSeconds`:

```py
import boto3

creds = boto3.client('sts').assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::0000000000000000:role/custom-role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1",
    DurationSeconds=10800 # 3 hours
)['Credentials']
    
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=creds['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=creds['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=creds['SessionToken']
)
s3_client = session.client('s3')
...
```

`DurationSeconds` can be up to 43200 (12 hours)

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts/client/assume_role.html

Comment: Thank you Paolo. I think your suggestion will work for me. I tried it and got error: `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The requested DurationSeconds exceeds the MaxSessionDuration set for this role.` So I think I'll have to work with AWS admin to increase MaxSessionDuration for the Role.

Comment: Thank you Paolo. I have accepted your answer